# How to list all post categories in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I was thinking of using the following code snippet but it does not return anything...

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.url }}"><strong>{{ category.title }}</strong></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm also using Jekyll's original [category page generator plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators), but I cannot figure out how to list all the post categories (for a blog page sidebar) that are being used?

Comment: What specific plugin are you using? The above link points to the generators doc.

Comment: @marcanuy Category page generator list under that section!

Answer (score 3):

Try this：

```html
{% for category in site.categories %}
    <li><a href="{{category.url}}"><strong>{{category|first}}</strong></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if something has changed, but something bad happened when I used Leon's answer (seemed like the loop never ended and I got an OOM). Here is what did work for me:

```
  {% for category in site.categories %}
    {% capture category_name %}{{ category | first }}{% endcapture %}
      <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/{{category_name}}">{{category_name}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

Source is the ever-helpful https://blog.webjeda.com/jekyll-categories/